# Windows Universal app: Bottom bar icons

Tags: windows-runtime, icons, size, win-universal-app

I have windows universal application, and I am using same icons of bottom appbar for both phone and tablet build. On phone the icons are ok but on tablet they are pixelated.

What Size should I use for bottom bar icons?

Comment: Currently I am using 76x76 images

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13323383/winphone-8-appbar-icon-size

Comment: In answer it shows 76x76. I am also using 76x76 but as I have already mentioned in question that it is pixelated in tablet only. In windows phone build same icon is good.

Answer (score -1):

It is weird but what I have done to correct is just ask designer to increase the blank space in images.

For example I have an icon with two lines like this `||` it is getting blur designer increased it space between these lines like this `| |` and problem solved. No more blur images now.