# WP8 tile design

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8, live-tile

Can't figure out how do I prepare the images for the Iconic tile on WP8. The guide is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207009%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). My tile is very simple - no counter, no variable text. Just the image and the app title.

So I should provide two image files - IconImage and SmallIconImage (the XML elements in the manifest are called differently, by the way). But which size should I make them? The guide says the tile is 159x159 and 336x336, respectively; but the icon within the tile is 110x110 and 202x202. The rest is text and counter, as overlaid by the Windows Phone shell.

Which size should I use for my two images? Should I just draw the icon, or a larger image some blank space and the icon in the required boundaries?

EDIT: relevant discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12837720/windows-phone-8-startscreen-tile-sizes-and-margins/13153522#13153522).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct size would be:
Small: 72×110
Medium: 132×202

You can find more details here http://mikaelkoskinen.net/windows-phone-8-iconic-tile-image-size-comparison

Comment: This is so weird. Why doesn't the guideline say so?

Answer (score 0):

The guide is showing that you make your icon 110x110 and 202x202. The 159x159 and 336x336 shown in the guide are noted for the size of the tile. If you want to use the Iconic Template, you do not create the entire tile like you used to. Instead you designate the icon to be used within the tile. Search for "icon" within this link. http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/What%27s_new_in_Windows_Phone_8