# Windows Phone 8 Tile size?

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8

where do i find informations which size my windows phone 8 icons should have?

what is the minimum amount of different icon sizes which i have to create to submit my app?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows Phone 8 Startscreen Tile sizes and margins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12837720/windows-phone-8-startscreen-tile-sizes-and-margins)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer in the WP8 documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windowsphone/design/jj662929(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: _Tiles on the Start screen come in three sizes—small, medium, and wide_ ... so helpful! Thank you MS! LOL

Answer (score 6):

Actually, you have Tile sizes on this page:
[Tiles for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202948%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: You need to multiply the value in 1.6 to account for screen resolutions.

Answer (score -1):

there is a picture with directly answer

http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC619133.png

**Small**
Flip and Cycle 159 × 159 pixels;
Iconic 110 × 110 pixels
**Medium**
Flip and Cycle 336 × 336 pixels;
Iconic 202 × 202 pixels
**Wide**
Flip and Cycle 691 × 336 pixels;
Iconic N/A

Comment: Except you're not accounting for high resolution screens. Thus, your answer is wrong.