# How to decide size for windows phone 8 in application images

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am working on Windows phone 8 native application development. In my application I need to use multiple images, logos. My confusion is how I will decide image resolutions for particular image or logo size. I have referred  MSDN for [multi-resolution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206974%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) screen but it is only for how to handel multi resolutions screen. Can anyone please suggest me how I will decide what exactly the size for my logo or images?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The artwork dimensions for the store are also [detailed on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/help/jj206723%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

On Windows Phone, you cannot specify different images for different screen resolutions. Instead, to handle all resolutions, you should scale your images to fit a 1080 x 1920 pixels resolution (Lumia 1520).

As Windows Phone will automatically upscale your images if necessary, using a high resolution image prevents it from being blurry, and when the image is downscaled for lower resolution devices, it'll also not be blurry.

For ApplicationBar / Tiles, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/12958512/95309 for details.

Answer (score 0):

There is a session on this subject from the most recent Build. This is perhaps more to do with Windows Store apps, but good info regardless to get your mind past all these resolution differences. @Claus Jørgensen's response probably more directly addresses your question.

[From 4 to 40 inches: Developing Windows Applications across Multiple Form Factors](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2014/3-541)

While there are some image sizes you need to provide (for the marketplace for example), you should be designing for shape and effective resolution. Check out the session. It should help clear this up.