# Windows Phone 8.1 tile sizes

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I want to update my Windows Phone 8 app to a Windows Phone 8.1, however I can't seem to find much information regarding tile sizes and images.

I found this:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh846296.aspx

Which is for Windows Store and guides to this:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh846296.aspx

Which only applies to Windows Phone 8 and Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 | Windows Phone OS 7.1.

Anyone knows which tile sizes are required for Windows Phone 8.1? To be specific I'm talking the images used in the Package.appxmanifest file.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows Phone 8 Startscreen Tile sizes and margins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12837720/windows-phone-8-startscreen-tile-sizes-and-margins)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These three sizes are available for Windows Phone 8.1, which you can provide in the  app's manifest file :

1) Small (71x71)

2) Medium (150x150)

3) Wide (310x150)

Images must have dimensions less than or equal to 1024x1024 pixels, have a file size of less than or equal to 200 KB, and be of type .png, .jpg, .jpeg, or .gif.

A tile is always pinned to the Start screen as a medium tile, though the user can then resize it.

There is also a Tiny (44x44) image available, but this not a tile and it is used only as a logo in search results and the Apps list.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj206971(v=vs.105).aspx) are the proper sizes of Windows Phone 8.1 tiles.

- small: 159 x 159 pixels
- medium: 336 x 336 pixels
- wide: 691 x 336 pixels

I use them in all my apps.

However, when you create a new Windows Phone 8.1 RT project, then you can check sizes of default images. They are a little bit bigger.

- small: **170 x 170** pixels
- medium: **360 x 360** pixels
- wide: **744 x 360** pixels

[image]

Using bigger images may be even better for high-resolution screens.