# Windows 10 Mobile Startscreen Tile sizes and margins

Tags: windows-10-mobile

Microsoft has changed the tile sizes and margins for Windows 10 Mobile [compared to Windows Phone 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12837720/windows-phone-8-startscreen-tile-sizes-and-margins). Does anyone know the exact measurements for margins (top, left & right, between tiles) edge length of different tile sizes and also the icon sizes within those tiles dependig on the screen resolution?

Comment: All you need to know about tiles can be found just right here :
https://dev.windows.com/en-us/design/assets
Download the pdf file and go directly to page 342 !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Universal Windows 10 Platform Microsoft really helps developers with creating and designing Universal Windows Apps.
I can advise two great sources to answer your question (and not only because below you can find many interesting hints how to design your app).

1. Official UWP app design guidelines (PDF):
   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=626098
2. Design & UI page: 
   https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/design

I think that with these you can create crafted to perfection. :)